# How can i get the numbers from a text part using indexof and substring or maybe HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to use first indexof and substring.

In html file i downloaded i have this part of text:

```
var arrayImageTimes = [];
arrayImageTimes.push('201702130145');arrayImageTimes.push('201702130200');arrayImageTimes.push('201702130215');arrayImageTimes.push('201702130230');arrayImageTimes.push('201702130245');arrayImageTimes.push('201702130300');arrayImageTimes.push('201702130315');arrayImageTimes.push('201702130330');arrayImageTimes.push('201702130345');arrayImageTimes.push('201702130400');
```

And i want to extract into a List or array only the numbers meaning in the end i will have for example a string List of:

```
201702130145
201702130200
201702130215
```

All the numbers between each ' '

I tried:

```
public void ExtractDateAndTimes(string f)
        {
            string startTag = "var arrayImageTimes = [];";
            string endTag = "</script>";
            int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
            int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
            int index = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                index = f.IndexOf(startTag, index);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // else more to do - index now is positioned at first character of startTag
                int start = index + startTagWidth;
                index = f.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                // found the endTag
                string g = f.Substring(start, index - start);
            }
        }
```

And in constructor:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Temp\testinghtml.html");
ExtractDateAndTimes(text);
```

But what i get is just the block of text of the var arrayImageTimes i added above.

Comment: Why are some numbers not in your result such as 201702130230?

Comment: @CodingYoshi You right. I just gave example of what i mean by parsing the numbers. But it should parse all of them not only what i showed as results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Regex` to find all matches into named capturing group using a [Named matched subexpression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#named_matched_subexpression):

```cs
// Don't forget to escape full stops!
// Capture quoted values inside round braces into imageTime capturing group
Regex regex = new Regex(@"arrayImageTimes\.push\('(?<imageTime>\d+)'\)", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(myString);

List<string> timestamps = new List<string>();

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    timestamps.Add(m.Groups["imageTime"].Value);
}
```